# ransack gem: Filter for years and months in dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I use Rails 5.1 and the current version of the ransack gem.

I have a "statistics" page where I show jobs and  I'd like to implement a filter functionality with two dropdown select fields, 1) years (2011-2018) and 2) months (jan-dec). How can I do that?

I was thinking of something like

```
# in statistics index view
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
  <%= f.grouping_fields(f.object.new_grouping) do |g| %>
    <%= g.condition_fields(g.object.new_condition) do |c| %>
      <%= # here the years dropdown list%>

      <%= # here the months dropdown list%>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "filter" %>
<% end %>
```

How should it look like correctly?

Comment: Are those years tied to your models? For now, I don't see any reasons to have nested inputs, you can just create two independent dropdowns (years, months)...

Comment: yeah, you're right! I was thinking too complicated...

Comment: @Trinity76 do you have years and months column in your model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it can be done by ransack or not, optionally you can do this by using simple form :- like this: -

```
<%= form_tag jobs_path, method: :get%>
  <%= select_year(Date.today, {:prompt => "Year",:start_year => DateTime.now.year,:end_year => DateTime.now.year - 7, prefix: 'start_date'},{:field_name => 'year', :id => 'start-year'}) %>
  <%= select_month(Date.today, {:prompt => "month",use_short_month: true, prefix: 'start_date'},{:field_name => 'month', :id => 'start-month'}) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search Job", :id=>"button", :class=>"Test", :name=>"submit") %>
<%end%>
```

and in your index action

```
def index
  if params[:year].present? or params[:month].present?
   #@jobs = Job.where("colum BETWEEN ? AND ?", ...)
   #@jobs = your_own_query_for_filter 
  else
    @jobs = Job.all
  end
end
```

i haven't written code properly, its just an example that you can do in this way also. hope it will help you.

Find here [for date select form helper](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/select_year)

Comment: I used in the view exactly your code snippet and modified the controller to: def index
    if params[:year].present? or params[:month].present?
      @jobs = Job.where("datum_auftrag BETWEEN #{params[:year]}-#{params[:month]}-01 AND #{Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}")
else #here the else branch 
end
  end
But a click on submit doesn't affect anything. Do you know, what I'm missing?

Comment: I tried this, too:    if params[:year].present? or params[:month].present?
      @jobs = Job.where("datum_auftrag BETWEEN ?-?-01 AND #{Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")},params[:year],params[:month]")

Comment: I created a new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301147/rails-search-for-years-and-months-from-drop-down-lists