# Rails: search for years and months from drop down lists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use Rails 5.1 and I'm trying to search with two dropdown select lists -1. years, 2. months - and a submit button.

In my view:

```
<%= form_tag jobs_path, method: :get do %>
<%= select_year(Date.today, {:prompt => "Year",:start_year => DateTime.now.year,:end_year => DateTime.now.year - 7, prefix: 'select'},{:field_name => 'year', :id => 'start-year'}) %>
  <%= select_month(Date.today, {:prompt => "month",use_short_month: true, prefix: 'select'},{:field_name => 'month', :id => 'start-month'}) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search Job", :id=>"button", :class=>"Test", :name=>"submit") %>
<%end%>
```

In my jobs_controller.rb:

```
  # GET /jobs.json
  def index
    if params[:year].present? or params[:month].present?
       month_with_leading_zero = params[:month].to_s.rjust(2, "0")
       start_date = "#{params[:year]}-#{month_with_leading_zero}-1"
       end_date = Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
       @jobs = Job.where("datum_auftrag BETWEEN ? AND ?", start_date, end_date)
    else
      @search = Job.ransack(params[:q])
      @jobs = @search.result
    end
  end
```

In my Database the date is saved in format: yyyy-mm-dd eg. 2011-01-20

A click on the submit button ignores the filtering instead prints all jobs:

> Started GET
>   "/jobs?utf8=%E2%9C%93&start_date%5Byear%5D=2016&start_date%5Bmonth%5D=1&submit=Search+Job"
>   for ::1 at 2018-01-17 14:01:54 +0100 Processing by
>   JobsController#index as HTML   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "start_date"=>{"year"=>"2016", "month"=>"1"}, "submit"=>"Search Job"} 
>   Rendering jobs/index.html.erb within layouts/application   Rendered
>   jobs/_job_links.html.erb (38.5ms)   Job Load (5.5ms)  SELECT `jobs`.*
>   FROM `jobs`    (1.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `manuscripts` WHERE
>   `manuscripts`.`job_id` = 20    (2.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
>   `manuscripts` WHERE `manuscripts`.`job_id` = 21

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 make a search form on your index page

```
<%= form_tag your_index_action_path, method: :get do%>
  <%= select_year(Date.today, {:prompt => "Year",:start_year => DateTime.now.year,:end_year => DateTime.now.year - 7, prefix: 'select'},{:field_name => 'year', :id => 'start-year'}) %>
  <%= select_month(Date.today, {:prompt => "month",use_short_month: true, prefix: 'select'},{:field_name => 'month', :id => 'start-month'}) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search Job", :id=>"button", :class=>"Test", :name=>"submit") %>
<%end%>
```

note:- replace `your_index_action_path` by path of your index action you ca get your path on console by running `rake routes`

2- on click submit button at controller side in you index action you will get following paramter

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "select"=>{"year"=>"2018", "month"=>"1"}, "submit"=>"Search Job", "controller"=>"jobs", "action"=>"index"} permitted: false>
```

so from here you need only `params[:select][:year]` and `params[:select][:month]`

```
def index
  if params[:select][:year].present? || params[:select][:month].present?
    start_date = (params[:select][:year]+"-" +params[:select][:month]+"-"+Date.today.day.to_s).to_datetime.beginning_of_day
    end_date = Date.today.end_of_day
    @jobs = Job.where("datum_auftrag BETWEEN ? AND ?",start_date, end_date)
  else
    @jobs = Job.all
  end
end
```

Note: -here it need to make custom date according to selected value and i have used`beginning_of_day` and `end_of_day` method to get more clear search result.

Earlier i have given you just a sample code, and you were expected to modify it, here i m giving you again solution , please do not just copy and paste use debugger and pry at controller side to get selected date and  year, however i m giving this answer practically done.

Comment: Gabbar, Thank you very much! I get "NoMethodError in JobsController#index
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
" on the line if params[:select][:year].present? ...

Comment: @Trinity76 could you put a debugger or pry at index action and check what params are comming from from?

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  
app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:15:in `index'
Started GET "/jobs?utf8=%E2%9C%93&start_date%5Byear%5D=2018&start_date%5Bmonth%5D=1&submit=Search+Job" for ::1 at 2018-01-17 14:29:49 +0100
Processing by JobsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "start_date"=>{"year"=>"2018", "month"=>"1"}, "submit"=>"Search Job"}
params[]: {"utf8"=>"✓", "start_date"=>{"year"=>"2018", "month"=>"1"}, "submit"=>"Search Job", "controller"=>"jobs", "action"=>"index"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: That's what I get after putting logger.debug "params[]: #{params}" right before the if params[:select][:year].present? ... statement

Comment: @Trinity76 could you replace the search_form html code with the same code given here in step=1 and lets try again , as i m seeing that you haven't replace the new html search form code. 
lets try again and  let me know for further guidance.

Comment: @Trinity76 replace these all codes to your old codes and just changes form_tag url and try again.

Comment: yes, you're right, now I updated the view with your code but it still shows the dame error: undefined method [] for NilClass. Thanks @Gabbar for your patience!

Comment: @Trinity76 paste your params that are you getting at index action .

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "select"=>{"year"=>"2018", "month"=>"1"}, "submit"=>"Search Job"}

Comment: @Trinity76 did you replace index action code witj new code that is given above in answer? If you have already replaced it than you should't not get this error.

Comment: @Trinity76 Yep as m seeing that your parameters are sent accordingly in correct format as i explained in above answer. But you haven't replaced index action code that why you are getting same error still .please read above answer. And do as i did. SO that you won't get these errors.

Comment: Yes, i thought i did replace the index action code fully but for some reason it wasn't. When I copy&paste it again, now it works! Thank you very much! I learned a lot!

Comment: Just a note: I experienced the same error again (I did copy it correctly at first time) and it happens when I refresh the page without any parameters. As a workaround I modified the index if statement to: if params.has_key?(:select)